# php pagination, displays nothing on next click

Tags: php, forms, pagination

I have created a website that is displaying bookings from a database. I'm only displaying 10 bookings per page, so I have created a pagination aswell. To get the bookings you have to set an ID, and I made everything work if I code the ID directly into the php-file. The thing I'm trying to do now is to get a select-form, so the user is able to select the ID by its own.

I created a select-form where I display all the IDs as options and I'm able to choose an ID and get out bookings, but when i press the "next" button everything disappears. If I now choose the ID again and update the page, then all the bookings for page 2 will appear. How can I solve this, so the next 10 bookings will be displayed when I press "Next"?

The php where I get the IDs for the select-form

```
<?php
$hejsann = array();
$hejsan = array();
$hej = 0;

$connect = server();
database();
$stmt = mssql_init("Stored_procedure", $connect);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);

while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
array_push($hejsan, utf8_encode($row['0'] . ' ' . $row['1']));  
array_push($hejsann, $row['0']);
}
?>
```

The select form:

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="taskOption" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose a group</option>

    <?php

    while($hej < count($hejsan)) {
        echo '<option value=' . $hej . '>' . $hejsan[$hej] . '</option>';
        $hej++;
    }

    ?>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Find bookings">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The pagination

```
$var = $_POST['taskOption'];
$book = bookings($hejsann[$var]);

$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if ($page < 1) $page = 1;

$resultsPerPage = 10;
$startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
$numberOfRows = count($book);
$totalPages = ceil($numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);

$output = array_slice($book, $startResults, $resultsPerPage);

$b = 0;
while($b < count($output)) {
    echo $output[$b];
    $b++;
}

if($page > 1) {
echo '<a href="?page='.($page - 1).'"><span>Back</span></a>&nbsp';
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
{
    if($i == $page)
        echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>&nbsp';
    else
        echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">'.$i.'</span></a>&nbsp';
}

if ($page < $totalPages) {
    echo '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">Next</span></a>&nbsp;';
}

if($page == $totalPages && $page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="?page=1"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">First</span></a>&nbsp';
}
```

If anything is unclear, please tell me. Very thankful for any help!

Comment: I'm wondering how you are combining $_GET and $_POST so easily?

Comment: What do you mean? Shouldn't it be possible? (I'm pretty new to PHP)

Comment: If your form method is <form method="post"> then only $_post or $_request will work..

Comment: Forgot to say, I get these error messages when I press "Next":

[Mon Apr 28 11:45:33 2014] [error] [client IP] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: taskOption in /var/www/html/Booking.php on line 124, referer: IP/Booking.php?page=1
[Mon Apr 28 11:45:33 2014] [error] [client IP] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  in /var/www/html/Booking.php on line 137, referer: IP/Booking.php?page=1

Comment: I don't see the problem straight away, but i'll give you a hint: Try to create a pagination for 1 item... Forget your selectbox and work out a pagination example that definatly works for 1 item. If that works well, try to change your code in a way you can choose by using a select box..